# Does losing reputation remove perks you've earned?

Tags: everdale

Upon reaching 20,000 reputation on the reputation tree, your reputation decays at a rate of 5% of the amount above 20,000 per day.

According to the wiki:

> Rewards are claimable only once, so even if you reached a milestone, went below and achieved it again, you won't get the rewards again.

However, what about perks such as the number of daily trades or maximum villager training level? Do these disappear to?

The UI seems to suggest you lose the perk, but as my valley has not progressed far enough, so I have no way of telling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes it does

For perks, you lose the perk as soon as you drop below the threshold.

You can see this by going past 26000 reputation and then let your reputation decay. Once below 26000, you'll notice your shipping tokens drop from the maximum of 9 to 8.

For one-time rewards, you can't claim them again.

However, with the removal of reputation decay, this won't happen anymore (besides for if your reputation somehow drops to 0).